# Dynamic vs Static NAT? How to tell which and when one or the other is in use?

Tags: networking, nat, ipv4

One source said that in NAT, multiple hosts share the same public IP address.

Then I found out there's another type of NAT, which is Dynamic NAT that translates one public IP into multiple public IPs that are dynamically given to multiple hosts. But wouldn't this introduce problems like possible duplicate public IPs?

I'm confused. Which one is commonly in use by consumers? when is each type of NAT necessary?

Comment: You are kind of mixing up source/destination NAT with Static/Dynamic NAT. Dynamic NAT just means that on the "remote" side of the NAT wall, addresses will be mapped from an assigned pool. both static and dynamic mapping do the same thing (forget public and private, its not important to static/dynamic). the question is whether you wrote a mapping rule for ever address on the left network, mapping it to a specific address on the right network (static mapping), or if you instead wrote no rules and just said "auto assign an address from this pool on right network to any address on left network"

Comment: @FrankThomas so does that means every hosts that are connected to the router have the same ip address as the router? or do they get assigned different ip addresses?

Comment: short answer is "it depends on how you are using NAT". in the case of statically mapped asymetric NAT, where the Right network has exactly 1 address in it, yes every address in the Left network will be mapped to the single address in the Right network (as you put it the "routers address" [specifically its WAN address]). if the Left network has 255 addresses, and the Right network has 5 addresses in its pool, you could dynamically map the first 51 addresses from Left to the first address in Right, the next 51 address from Left to the second address from Right, and so on and so forth.

Comment: So the conceptual difficulty you are having, is that home routers represent only 1 (maybe 2) of the 3 major ways NAT is used. the things you are studying are coming from the perspective of someone who is comfortable with all 3 of them, so when you try to apply the concepts to just the 1 topic (home internet access) a lot of the ideas just don't fit. static vs dynamic is one of those concepts, as is symmetric NAT, since most home users have multiple devices, but don't have multiple WAN IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question as asked, a standard consumer grade internet access router provides *staticly-mapped* , *asymetric*, *source* NAT, when it is allowing its LAN hosts to share a single public IP from the ISP. That said though, you are mixing up a number of NAT's fundamental characteristics.

First, most people think of home internet access routers when they think of NAT, but that is just one common usecase, and in it, static vs dynamic isn't particularly relevant.

first understand that a NAT mapping is always mapping one address from the left network to one address on the right network. a NAT implementation maps a set of addresses on the left to a set of addresses on the right.

in *symetric* NAT there are an equal number of addresses in the left network and in the right network that can be mapped to, so each address on the left is mapped to an address on the right that no other address from the left is mapped to. A -> Z, B -> Y, C -> X, etc. in *asymmetric* NAT the left network has more addresses than the right network does (note, *left* and *right* are completely arbitrary and interchangeable here).

Since you are asking about Static vs  Dynamic, you are asking about how the NAT implementation maps a given address in L to an address in R. there are basically two ways to do that:

1. you can configure a mapping rule for every address in L, telling the router what the address in R will be explicitly. This is static mapping. its a real pain if there are many addresses in L and/or R. In the case of your home internet access router, it maps all addresses in L (your LAN) to a single address in R (your public IP). Note that whether or not your public IP is assigned by an ISP DHCP server doesn't matter.
2. you can just tell the router "map every address in L to an address from this pool of addresses from R automatically". This is a dynamic mapping. its much easier to set up when there are many addresses in R, since you don't have to configure a bunch of rules, or change anything when new addresses are added to L. Dynamic mapping is only really meaningful when there is more than one address in R.

*Source/Destination NAT* are a way to think about asymmetric NATs, where you establish a perspective (like public vs private). For a home-grade router, L is the LAN and R is the WAN. *Source* NAT maps all the addresses in L to (usually a smaller number of) addresses in R (in the home-grade router case its usually 1).  This allows all the computers on the LAN to share a public IP.  *Destination* NAT is what people often call Port Forwarding, and in the home router case, allows many addresses on the internet to be mapped to a single address on the LAN (the address of the L interface of the router), so that people can access your public minecraft server (or whatever else).

So Static vs Dynamic mapping just refers to how you configure the mapping of all L -> R.

NAT is generally transparent to the systems in both networks, so under most circumstances you cannot tell easily that a NAT is there at all.